# How to have different MenuItem for different fragment inside same activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem

I have tabbar of fragment and I need MenuItem for each fragment.

[image]

if I show fragment1 have menuItem1,
if I show fgrament2 have menuItem2.
Any idea? I hope that somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Flags` for each `Fragment` and according to the flag you can inflate the Menus you want with the help of `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method,,